# Identifying exact location of data entry issues when bulk copying or importing from excel to access

Tags: vba, ms-access

One of the requirements of a project that I have is to allow users to import or copy and paste in bulk a few hundred rows from excel to access. However, there is a reasonable chance due to human error that there will be some data validation issues between the imported data and the table structure/referential integrity rules. I would like to be able to identify exactly the field/s and record/s where these issues are occuring so that I can point them out to the user for correction.

As such the standard error essages like 'you cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in...' or 'data type mismatch in criteria or expression' are not descriptive enough to the exact location of the problem so even if I catch them I can't really give a better descriptor anyway

I am debating importing to a completely free text temporary table, then looping an insert to move one row at a time from the temp table to the properly validated table and using dbfailonerror to catch issues on individual records that need correction (the user needs to correct them I can't do this through code)

My question is whether this is a reasonable approach, is there a better/easier way, or a way to get a more specific error from access rather than using a loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this.  I'm not sure what method you are using to do the import but if is as simple as copying rows from the excel sheet to the table Access will generate a Paste_errors table that will show the rows it couldn't import.  The wizard will do the same thing but I think its prone to crashing.

The way I typically do it is actually have the end user use an excel template with a VBA backend that does the uploading.  You can check each value conditionally and give a better descriptive alert and/or shuttle any defective rows to a temporary table for you to review.

You can do this the opposite way and do the import through Access VBA but that would be more coding since you would have to create an Excel object in code, open the sheet, etc.

I setup a Quickbooks export of a accounts receivable table by creating a User DSN on the local machine pointing to the Access file, opening an ADO recordset and looping through the rows one column at a time applying logic to each row.

Quickbooks would ask for an existing file to dump the data into so I made that a template file on the network.  It sounds like your users may have to enter directly into the spreadsheet so you would have to distribute the template but the results are the same.

Example of Looping through the sheet and validating rows

Create a DSN file to the database and store it on a shared drive, this way you don't have to hardcode the string and if you need to change something, you only have to change the dsn file instead of redistributing templates.

```
Public Sub Upload


'Declare the main recordset that the records will be uploaded to.
Dim rstUpload as New Adodb.Recordset

'Declare a utility recordset object that you can reuse to check referential tables
Dim rstCheck as New Adodb.recordset

'Declare a utility command object that you can reuse to check referential tables
Dim SQLCommand as New Adodb.Command

'Declare the connection object to the database
Dim dataConn as New Adodb.Connection

'A tracking flag if you find something in a row that won't upload
Dim CannotUpload as Boolean

'Open the connection to the access database
dataConn.Open "\\Server\Share\Mydatabase.dsn" 'Your dsn file'

Set SQLCommand.ActiveConnection = DataConn


rst.Open "yourTable", dataConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic

For i = 1 to 100 ' Rows 
*You may want to do a pass through the rows so you can get an accurate count, usually just loop through the rows until a column that must have data is blank.  If your users are skipping rows that is going to be a problem.


     rstUpload.AddNew

     'Set the tracking Flag to False indicating you can upload this row, this will be changed if any field cannot be validated
     CannotUpload = False


     'First Column/Field: 'Non critical field, any value will do

          rstUpload("Field1").Value = Range(i,1).Value          '


     'Second Column/Field has a referential integrity constraints
     'Run a query against the table that has the values you are trying to validate.
          SQLCommand.CommandText = "Select IDField From YourTable where ID = " & Range(i,2).Value  
          Set rstCheck = SQLCommand.Execute

     'Check if any records were returned, if none than the value you are checking is invalid

          If rstCheck.RecordCount > 0 Then 'we matched the value in the cell
               rstUpload ("Field2").Value = Range(i,2).Value 
          else
              'Design a flagging method, maybe highlight the cell in question
               CannotUpload = True
          End if

....continue through your columns in the same fashion, reusing the SQLCommand Object and the Utility recordset when you need to lookup something in another table



        'After last column
        If CannotUpload = False Then
             'Nothing triggered the flag so this row is good to go
             rstUpload.Update
        Else 
             'Cannot Upload is true and this row won't be uploaded
             rstUpload.Cancel
        End If

Next i

dataconn.Close
set dataConn = Nothing
set rstUpload = Nothing
set rstCheck = Nothing
set SQLCommand = Nothing
```

Comment: I did try some manual copy and pasting but it was producing some very odd results in terms of just skipping some of the rows depending if certain fields were blank so I'm probably going to use 'DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet' with filedialog to enable the user to pick the file. I should have stressed more in the question but the reason I wanted to do this in access end rather than excel end is the **referential integrity** rules. There are tables pulled back when the file opens and I need to validate that certain entered values exist in these tables, not sure how I'd validate in excel?

Comment: For those columns with referential integrity restraints, open a recordset to that table and query for the value.  I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'd take the reverse approach of turning the excel into a recordset because I won't necessarily know the location of the database if I distribute it whereas the user will have just located the excel through the dialog picker.

Comment: I'm going to play devil's advocate here for the sake of debate though. I was taking the approach of using the referential integrity because I was under the impression it was one of ms-access strengths. Why would your approach be to try and replicate it's functionality in excel if the end result either way is that we need to loop each record? (I'm not ungrateful for your contribution here just trying to flesh out the solution and reasons)

Comment: It's not optimal but without any way to monitor what your end users are doing, from either end this is what's going to be needed.  Could you have the end users enter this sheet into a Access front end with a simple form instead of the excel sheet?  If you duplicate the table structure it should make it much easier.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the data they will enter already exists in excel sheets that they maintain themselves, the ability to move this across in bulk is one of the requirements here